# PHP Firebase input is inputting blank instead of the submitted value?

Tags: php, firebase

I am working on a grading system but whenever I input a grade, it saves a blank instead of the submitted value.

The form is on the table itself and not on a separate page. I know doing it on a separate page will solve my problem but I want to do it on the table itself.

[Like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oDAye.png)

Here is the code for the table

```
<tr> 
 <th>Student Number</th>
 <th>Course</th>
 <th>Email</th>
 <th>Name</th>
 <th>Grade</th>
 <th>Remark</th>
 <th>Add/Edit</th>
<?php
$table = "Users";
$fetch = $database->getReference($table)->getValue();
if($fetch > 0)
{
   foreach($fetch as $key => $row)
  {
    ?>
    <tr>
     <td> <?= $row['Student_number']; ?> </td>
     <td> <?= $row['Course']; ?> </td>
     <td> <?= $row['Email']; ?> </td>
     <td> <?= $row['Name']; ?> </td>
    <?php
     if(!$row['grade']
       {
       ?>
        <td><input type = "text" name = "grade" id = "grade"></input></td>
        <td><button type = "submit" name = "update" value = "<?=$key?>"</button></td>
        <td>N/A</td>
       }
      else
      {
        ?>
        <td><?=$row[grade];?></td>
        <?php
      }
  }

}
?>
```

And here is the code for the input

```
if(isset($_POST[update]))
{
 $key = $_POST[update];
 $grade = $_POST[grade];
 $postGrade = ['grade' => $grade,];

 $table = 'Users;
 $updateResult = $database->getReference($table)->update($postGrade);
}
```

I need help finding what's wrong with my code that makes the input a blank instead of the intended submitted value.

Comment: Key names for arrays should be in quotes, so `$_POST[update]` should be `$_POST['update']` etc (the same goes for all usage of `$_POST`). Where are your form tags in the HTML? Where exactly does it fail? What debugging have you done? Do you get the data at all in PHP, or is it the database update that fails? What does `$row` contain? Btw, `$row[grade]` should also be `$row['grade']`.

Comment: Oh sorry for not being transparent. I didnt include the form tags because I was avoiding the "most of your post are just codes" warning, and also this isnt my actual code, just a simplified one so that it would be easy to read. Thats why i forgot to put the quotes on the 'updates' but they are there in my original code. The form tags are correct. This code IS working, but somehow, its inputting blank values instead of the submitted values. the 'grade' column is being added to the database, but its blank and thats what troubling me.

Comment: PHP will overwrite form parameters with the same name, unless you use square brackets in the name. You have _multiple_ rows that all contain an input field `name = "grade"` - when you submit this form, all the values will overwrite each other, and only the value you entered into the very last field, will arrive inside your script. How do you actually _want_ this to behave - do you want it to update only the record corresponding to the line where you clicked the "Save" button? Even if there was text input in the fields on any other line, you want that to simply be ignored?

Comment: If so, then put the key into the field name, `name="grade[<?=$key?>]"`. `$_POST['grade']` will be an array then, still containing entries for _all_ the text fields; but you can pick out the relevant one, by using `$_POST['update']` as the key.

Comment: yes i do want it to update the record corresponding to the line of the Save button